# How can i change the languae of the keyboard?

Tags: xcode

My app has a language selection option where all the text can be changed to display their selected language. is it possible to change the text of the keyboard programatically? Right now they can choose from english, french, chinese and spanish. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible in iPhone as it allows the user to change only the keyboard language from the Settings > General > Keyboard. However, you can change keyboard language by pressing Globe Icon which is given at left-bottom in the keyboard but before changing it you must have added different languages in keyboard.

Comment: Yea thats what i thought. iPhone keyboards language is changed by the user and not by the system thanks. My answer will be not possible thnaks